# How to customize look and feel of Lightning Web Components(LWC) base components?

Tags: lightning-web-components

In my below code, I want to add my own styling and add an icon from static resource. Salesforce doesn't provide the attributes eg class, id etc to LWC like it does in lightning components. Is there a way to do that or I have to create a custom tab using SLDS blueprint for tabs.

```
<template>
<lightning-tabset>
    <lightning-tab label="Item One">
        Content for tab 1
    </lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab label="Item Two">
        Content for tab 2
    </lightning-tab>
</lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add a utility icon via iconName. If you need greater customization, you'll have to write your own component(s).